# Hibernate mapping table for subclass

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I have 3 classes:

```
Person {
    int id;
    String name;
    String lastName;
}

Employee extends Person {
    //some additional data
}

Owner extends Person {
    //some additional data
}
```

For each class I have separate table. In `Employee` table the key should be exactly the same as in `Person` table.

And now when I insert `Employee` class there should be one record in `Person` table, one in `Employee` with the same `ID` (lets assume this is value 1).

After that I want to insert Owner class and I want it to be the same Person (ID=1) so after inserting Owner It should be added only one record in table Owner, but record in table Person should be left as it is.

I have tried this: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-subclass-annotation-xml-mapping/

Inserting first class is OK, inserting second with diffrent ID is ok, getting objects from db is ok, but whet I want to add Owner class with the same ID such as the existing person I got hibernateException... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's plain impossible. Since Java only has single inheritance, an object can't be both an employee and an owner. You shouldn't use inheritance to map these associations.

Instead, you should have Person have a OnetoOne association with its Employee role, and a OnetoOne association to its Owner role.

Comment: "It's plain impossible." In my code example Employee extends Profile and Owner exstends Profile.

Comment: If a Java object is an instance of Owner, it's can't be an instance of Employee, and vice-versa. So Hibernate wouldn't be able to tell which kind of entity to return when loading a person by ID whcih would have a row both in the employee and in the owner table. It's impossible.

Comment: I understend this, but I was hoping than there is a way to cheet hibernate by replacing inheritance by implementing interface, or by living inheritance in code, but in hibernate make a composition ex. Owner exstends AbstractPerson, and AbstractPerson contains Preson as field, but I don't know how to map this in hibernate becouce I don'ts have access to person field from parent i mapping file :/ And my second problem is that I want to Person ID was primary key also in Owner class...

Answer (score 0):

"It's plain impossible." In my code example Employee extends Profile and Owner exstends Profile.

If I understend corectlly you anwser you suggest something like this:

```
Person{
Employee emp;
Owner owner;
}
```

In my first class hierarhy I was able to do:

```
Person getPersonFromDb( Class class, int id){  ...  session.get(class, id) ... }

Owner o = (Owner) getPersonFromDb(Owner.class, id);
Employee e =(Employee) getPersonFromDb(Employee.class, id);
```

In your approach I can't have something like this...

Comment: Answers should not be used to comment on other answers. Use comments to do that, or edit your question. And see the comment I posted on my answer.